# Python 3 dicts display different behavior from dict.fromkeys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In Python 3, if I create a dict from `dict.fromkeys` then it displays a different behavior than just assigning a dict to a variable. I could see this when I used `extend` on both dicts.

```
dict_a = dict.fromkeys(['x', 'y', 'z'], [])
dict_b = {'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': []}

dict_a == dict_b  # returns True
type(dict_a) == type(dict_b)  # returns True

def test_dicts(d):
    d['z'].extend([1, 2, 3])
    print(d)
```

`test_dicts(dict_a)` returns

```
{'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [1, 2, 3], 'z': [1, 2, 3]}
```

`test_dicts(dict_b)` returns

```
{'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Is this expected behavior? If so, why?

Comment: You're only ever creating *one* list object there with `[]`, which gets assigned to all keys.

Comment: Just to be clear, this isn't specific to `fromkeys` but more to the way python works, try `l = [[]] * 10` and `l[0].append(42)`.